# failed to get nested json value into ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs

My data:

```
var user = [{
    'uId': 1,
    'name': 'eldy',
    'relationship': [{
        'uId':2,
        'name': 'Jeremy',
        'tabs':[{
                'tabId':1
            }],
        'tasks':[{
                'name':'tasks 1 of Jeremy Lin'
            }, {
                'name':'tasks 1 of Jeremy Lin'
            }, {
                'name':'tasks 1 of Jeremy Lin'
            }],
        'points': 50
        },

        {
            'uId':3,
        'name': 'Jordon',
        'tabs':[{
                'tabId':2
            }],
        'tasks':[{
                'name':'Im Jordon'
            }],
        'points': 100
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to access the tasks of the relationship array, I tried

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in user">
    <li ng-repeat="tasks in user.relationship.tasks">
        {{tasks[0].name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

but it returned blank. I always have problem working with nested json, any tools to help with that?

Comment: `relationship` is an array, so you need to specify the index.

Comment: I think you want to do `use.relationship[0].tasks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably bad practise to have "user in user" as it is slightly ambiguous. Try renaming your variable "users" to avoid confusion.

Next you'll need to either add another repeat for relationship, as this is an array, or to print only the first user:

```
user.relationship[0].tasks.
```

Edit:

Here is a Fiddle showing how it can be done with an extra ng-repeat http://jsbin.com/diyefevi/7/edit?html,js,output